# Creating dynamic textbox using Javascript and asp.net

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a JavaScript function that asks for a user input for a label, and then creates a textbox with the user input label.

I've gotten my code to come up with the user input prompt, but it does not create the textbox after the input is entered. Most resources I've found have told me to use the attribute innerHTML to add the text to my textbox, but it seems this attribute does not exist (I'm using MS Visual Studio as a DE).

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function addObject() {
          var element = prompt("Please enter fuel or insert ID", "");
          var box = document.createElement("TextBox");
          box.innerHTML = element;
          document.body.appendChild(box);   
     }
</script> 

<button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="javascript:addObject();">Add Fuel Element</button>
```

If an input of "abcd" is entered, I expect a textbox with the label "abcd" to be created. No textbox is created at all. I do not get any error messages or warnings, so I think the object is just not being created for some reason.

Updated my code to the following. Still not working. Same issues: no error messages and no textbox created.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addObject() {
           // creates new fuel or insert element
           var element = prompt("Please enter fuel or insert ID", ""); // gets element ID from user
           var box = document.createElement("textarea"); // creates element
           var textNode1 = document.createTextNode(element);
           box.appendChild(textNode1);
           document.body.appendChild(box);
     </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the tag name which you want to create as a parameter to the [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) in this case a `textarea` you were providing `TextBox` which is an invalid tag.

```html
<script>
     function addObject() {
          var element = prompt("Please enter fuel or insert ID", "");
          var box = document.createElement("textarea");
          box.innerHTML = element;
          document.body.appendChild(box);   
     }
</script> 

<button onclick="addObject()">Add Fuel Element</button>
```

Comment: I just tried this but it still does not create the textbox.

Comment: There are no errors or warnings. When the button is clicked, the prompt window is opened so that a user input can be entered. Nothing happens when the input is entered.

Comment: @PreronaKundu but in my answer, you can see the text box getting appended

Comment: I do see that. I'm not sure why it's not working in my own code.

Comment: Oh I just saw your answer after I posted mine +1

Answer (score 1):

In your revised code replace

```
var textNode1 = document.createTextNode(element);

box.appendChild(textNode1);
```

with

```
box.innerHTML = element;
```

so the 
code is:

```
  <body>
  <script>
      function addObject() {
            var element = prompt("Please enter fuel or insert ID", "");
            var box = document.createElement("textarea");
            box.innerHTML = element;
            document.body.appendChild(box);   
      }

  </script> 
  <button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="javascript:addObject();">Add Fuel Element</button>


  </body>
```

Comment: This is what I tried earlier, if you look at the first version of my code. It was not working either.

Comment: But that was also using 'TextBox' rather than 'textarea' as per Kunal's answer ?

Comment: I updated it to say "textarea", as per the comment thread on Kunal's answer. Still did not work.

Comment: I have just added the full code that also works for me.

Comment: This is what Kunal posted earlier and something I have already tried. Unfortunately, for some reason this code does not work in the Visual Studio DE. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. My original script was inside a form within the body. Deleted the two lines of code for the form, and everything works. Thank you to everybody!

Original code:

```
<body>
<form id="form1", runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">

        function addObject() {
            var label = prompt("Please enter fuel or insert ID", "");
            var box = document.createElement("button");
            box.appendChild(document.createTextNode(label));
            box.setAttribute("disabled", "");
            document.body.appendChild(box);
        }
       </script> 
    <button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="addObject()">Add Fuel Element</button>
</form>
</body>
```

Working code:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

        function addObject() {
            var label = prompt("Please enter fuel or insert ID", "");
            var box = document.createElement("button");
            box.appendChild(document.createTextNode(label));
            box.setAttribute("disabled", "");
            document.body.appendChild(box);
        }
       </script> 
    <button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="addObject()">Add Fuel Element</button>
</body>
```